# QMutex locked by unknown thread

Tags: qt, qthread, qmutex

In the following code, I get an ASSERT in `unlock ()`, because lockingThreads (a `QList<QThread*>`) does not contain the unlocking (current) thread.
Examining lockingThreads, I find an "ntdll" thread that I have no idea what it does and only disassembly can be accessed which doesn't provide useful information.
The problem is very hard to reproduce, so thanks for any hint (probably a stupid twist in this logic).

Edit: the mutex is recursive.

```
MyMutex::MyMutex (QMutex::RecursionMode mode)
: QMutex (mode)
, lockCount (0)
{
}

MyMutex::~MyMutex ()
{
    ASSERT (lockingThreads.isEmpty ());
}

void MyMutex::lock ()
{
    lockCount++;
#if MYDEBUG
    // grab thread before lock so we can identify it if it deadlocks here
    QThread* thread = QThread::currentThread ();
    if (!isRecursive ())
    {
        ASSERT (!lockingThreads.contains (thread));
        if (!lockingThreads.contains (thread))
            lockingThreads += thread;
    }
    else
        lockingThreads += thread;
#endif

    QMutex::lock ();
}

void MyMutex::unlock ()
{
#if MYDEBUG
    QThread* thread = QThread::currentThread ();
    ASSERT (lockingThreads.contains (thread));
    lockingThreads.removeOne (thread);
    if (lockingThreads.contains (thread) && !isRecursive ())
        ASSERTFALSE;
#endif
    QMutex::unlock ();
    lockCount--;
}
```

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve].  Apart from anything else your implementations of `MyMutex::lock` and `MyMutex::unlock` modify `lockCount` and other state while the mutex itself is potentially not locked.  Also note that `QMutex` has no (as far as I can see) virtual members and is, therefore, probably not a good base for inheritance.

Comment: As stated it is very hard to reproduce and the actual target is rather complex. QMutex::(un)lock () is always executed, and lockCount is irrelevant here. My question is really if/why there could ever be a currentThread locking the mutex that is entirely unknown, or if there is an error in the logic.

Comment: Yes there *is* an error in your logic (specifically a race condition) for the reasons specified.  Consider what happens if multiple threads all call `MyMutex::lock` at the same time.  They all potentially modify `lockingThreads` simultaneously.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: yes, that did occur to me too, even though that's not the problem I'm chasing. Anyway, thanks for the response.